# Django ModelForms - How to set default values for junction table

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm using ModelForms to populate two tables with a Many-to-Many relationship.  To simplify the problem description,  I'll use the typical example, where there is a Pizza table and a Toppings table, and a pizza can have many toppings and a topping can be on many pizzas.  The real application  has more  complicated tables, but I think it comes down to the relationships defined here:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships

A junction table, where each record consists of pizza_id and a topping_id and a create_time, ties the two tables together.  The application has a Modelform for the pizza and the toppings tables, but only a model (no ModelForm) for the junction table.  The junction table records are created automatically by django because of the Many-to-Many relationship between the tables.  The Pizza model has this "field" :

```
toppings=models.ManyToManyField (Topping, through=PizzaToppingJunction)
```

to define the ManyToMany relationship.

In this example, the "create_time field is required to be not null. (Note:  There are additional fields, i.e a user id field, and a "deleted" boolean that I need to set.  I'm using create_time as an example).

When the Pizza record is saved, django tries to create the junction table but fails because it has no value for the required field.  I'm guessing I should use "through_defaults" but I have not been successful.

I tried catching the m2m_changed signal and adding the relationships to pk_set:

```
(pizza.toppings.add ( topping, through_defaults = {"create_time": instance_time})
```

That (understandably) results in a recursion error.

I tried manually creating them:

```
PizzaToppingsJunction.objects.create (create_time = instance_tine, pizza_id = pizza_id, topping_id = topping_id).
```

That doesn't seem to have any effect on downstream processing because django attempts to create junction table records that are missing the required field. I think the code clears that table after the m2m_changed signal, so that makes sense.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`PizzaToppingJunction.create_time` can have [`auto_now_add=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) this will automatically set the value to the time the record was created

```
create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then you do not need to set any default values in the form

Comment: That's good to know, thank you!
I may have oversimplified the problem though.  I also have to pass the user id to the record.  There is a "user" column on the table that comes from the request.   Is there an easy way to set that?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the extra fields in the junction records works if it's done during the "m2m_changed" signal processing.  I'm not sure this is the right way to do it, but so far it's the only thing I could come up with.  The code below needs to be cleaned up, but it is generally what worked for me.

Using the pizza scenario:

```
    def m2m_changed_signal (self, sender, **kwargs):
        django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed.disconnect (self.m2m_changed_signal, sender=models.Pizza.toppings.through)

        instance_time = django.utils.timezone.now()
        instance_user = self.request.user.username

        pizza = kwargs ["instance"]
        pizza_id = pizza.pizza_id
        topping_ids = []
        for topping_id in kwargs ["pk_set"]:
            topping = models.Topping.objects.filter (topping_id = topping_id) [0]
            pizza.toppings.add ( topping, through_defaults = {"create_user": instance_user, "create_time": instance_time, "update_user": instance_user, "update_time":instance_time, "deleted": False})
            topping_ids.append (topping_id)

        for topping_id in topping_ids:
            kwargs  ["pk_set"].remove (topping_id)
```

Removing the elements from pk_set was needed to avoid duplicate (with null values for the created_by, etc, columns) records.

Any suggestions for improvements would be appreciated.